# Minimising the time of an object falling under gravity?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, variational-principle, brachistochrone-problem

The first step of this task (the only step I am actually stuck with), is to prove that the time taken for an object to fall between two points, O and A, is given by:
$$\Delta t~=~\frac{1}{\sqrt{2g}}\int \frac{\sqrt{1 + y'^2}}{\sqrt{y}} {\rm d}x.$$
We are asked to prove this using law of conservation of energy. Also, the $y$ in this equation is a function of $x$.

I started by writing the kinetic and potential energy at the start and end points, but then realised that $y = y(t)$, and I needed $y=y(x)$. I suspect this is where the integral comes into play, but I am not sure how.

To get rid of the time dependence, I tried to use equations of motion for constant gravity to write everything in terms of $x$, but this just ended cancelling everything out.

Any guidelines/tips would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  In the simplest scenario, constant gravity field, the question can be solved using basic kinematics, and $x$ (horizontal coordinate?) is not involved.   Have you left something out of the question?

Comment: Hi  and welcome to StackExchange. Take a look at the [help] to learn how this site works. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the equation of orbit is $y(x)$. Suppose the starting point of the orbit is $(0,0)$, the terminal of the orbit is $(x_0,y_0)$. Then the velocity of the object as point $(x,y(x))$ is given by energy conservation $v^2 = 2gy$, i.e.
$$v = \frac{ds}{dt} =\frac{\sqrt{dx^2+dy^2}}{dt} = \sqrt{1+y'^2} \frac{dx}{dt} = \sqrt{2gy}$$ 
Then, we have
$$dt = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2g}} \frac{\sqrt{1+y'^2}}{\sqrt{y}}dx$$
After integration, we have
$$T = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2g}} \int_0^{x_0} \frac{\sqrt{1+y'^2}}{\sqrt{y}}dx.$$
Then, we can use variation method to get the orbit $y(x)$ which minimize $T$,i.e.
$$\frac{\delta T}{\delta y(x)} = 0.$$
[image]